# Android: Databinding expression with enum comparison

Tags: android, data-binding, enums

is it possible to create a databinding expression and control the visibility of a view element by using enumerations? What I want to achieve is the following

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="@{user.editType == EditType.EDIT_PROFIL ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}">
```

The EditType class is very simple

```
public enum EditType {
  NONE,
  EDIT_PROFIL,
  EDIT_ADDRESSES; }
```

It would be awesome if I can use this enumeration within the XML to control the visibility of my `LinearLayout`.

Anybody got an idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

To me it seems like what you want to achieve is possible and I dont see anything wrong except maybe u lack of the  tag? I dont see it...

```
<data>
 <import type="com.example.my.app.EditType"/>
</data>
```

Comment: If you use a custom constructor for you enum it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I would recommed you to separate the logic from the UI. All logic of the visibility should be done in java code in diferent events. I would say something like @Demo_Mail suggested would work if implemented on the OnCreate() method of your Activity/Fragment but reading the data-binding tag suggests me that you want to do this dynamically, at any point in the run (correct me if Im wrong). In that case I would suggest to create an OnClick() or OnSelectItem() method that will be executed in the moment the user selects a value of the enum (in a comboBox for example). This method will set the visibility of the view.

Comment: No not dynamically. At the start of onCreate I once set the databinding resource and with this I want to control the visibility. It would be much more readable if I can use the enum in the xml. Otherwise I have to reference every LinearLayout within my code...:D

Comment: To me it seems like what you want to achieve is possible and I dont see anything wrong except maybe u lack of the <data> tag? I dont see it...

 <data>
    <import type="com.example.my.app.EditType"/>
</data>

Comment: Great thank you :) The <data> <import type="com.example.my.app.EditType"/> </data> line does the trick. If you post this as answer I'll mark it as the correct solution and you'll get some reputation :)